# How to remove or customize Gmail's "Quick Settings" menu?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, user-interface

In May 2020, Google announced a change to Gmail's settings menu: a new Quick Settings menu carrying some frequently used options was added.

The announcement and full description are at https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/05/new-gmail-quick-settings-optimize-inbox.html.

Here is a screenshot of this new menu:
[image: Quick settings Gmail menu]

Since I do not use any of the options on the new menu and anyway click on "See all settings" (because I need to access the 'Account and Import' settings,) **how can this new Quick Settings menu be removed?**

In other words, what should I do to have the original 'full' setting menu be displayed immediately after clicking the "settings" button?

*Alternatively*, how can I customize the Quick Settings Menu, for example by adding an 'Account and Import' settings button for faster access to these settings?

I have been searching for solutions on Google for weeks with queries like "gmail disable quick settings" or "turn off gmail quick settings", but I have not found any. In fact, no page I have encountered even discusses removing or modifying the Quick Settings menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the only way to skip the "Quick settings" menu is to directly append or modify the hash part of the URL to `#settings`. For example, if your URL is:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
```

then change `inbox` to `settings` and press Enter:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings
```

This will take you directly to the full settings. You could try saving this as a bookmark, although it depends on the browser whether the page would reload or not.

<sub>If you want the Settings icon in Gmail to take you directly to the full settings, you could only achieve that through browser-side scripting. It will only apply to your own browser where the scripting hack is active.</sub>

Comment: Modifying the URL works very well for me! I haven't tried the other two suggestions yet, but if/when I do, I will update this comment. As this is currently the only answer to this question, it gets accepted! Great thanks!